# open source monitoring solution without the need of an agent

Tags: python, open-source, monitoring

I am looking for an open source monitoring solution (preferably in Python) that works with ssh or snmp and does not require the installation of an agent (like Nagios, ZenOSS, munin).

Are you aware of such a solution?

Comment: What information do you want to get? Process liveness, CPU, memory usage etc..?

Comment: @Adam. Indeed! Thanks for the reminder

Comment: @EnnoShioji: basic info as cpu/memory usage to start, and if it is alloweb by snmp, processes/ports.

Comment: I could do this for you but I would want payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All tools that allow you to run scripts to gather metrics can basically run commands over a ssh connection on the target box.

The question is though if this makes a lot of sense as you rely on the network connection always being available and for each (set of) property(s) you need to run a new remote connection with all its overhead.

Snmp does by definition of the protocol require you to run an snmp agent on the target box.